# jQuery .on event trigger working differently for two forms?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have asked the first part of this question before, but with no answer to it though. I managed to bind one event to the form, but to one of the forms nothing seems to work.

So, this is one of the forms I'm dynamically echoing in the HTML:

```
$regex = '/^.*(\d{4,4})_(\d{2,2})_(\d{2,2}).*$/';
$replacement = '$3 / $2 / $1';
$val = preg_replace($regex,$replacement,$name);             

$formReplacement = 'backup-$3-$2-$1';
$formID = preg_replace($regex,$formReplacement,$name);

$form = array(
        '<form name="rollback-form" id="' . $formID . '" class="rollback-form" method="post" action="#">',
            '<fieldset class="rollback-fields">',
                '<fieldset class="display-rollback-wrapper">',
                    '<label for="display-rollback" class="display-rollback-label">Backup</label>',
                    '<input type="text" name="display-rollback" class="display-rollback" value="' . $val . '" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" />',
                    '<input type="hidden" name="rollback_id" value="' . $id . '" />',
                '</fieldset>',
                '<fieldset class="rollback-wrapper">',
                    '<button type="submit" name="rollback" class="rollback">Rollback</button>',
                '</fieldset>',
            '</fieldset>',
        '</form>',
        '<div  id="' . $formID . '-message-handling" class="message-handling" class="message-handling"></div>'
    );
$form = implode("", $form);
echo $form;
```

In the above case, `$name = $id = 'logindb_backup_2012_02_02.sql'`.

And I'm applying the following jQuery function to the echoed form:

```
$('form.rollback-form').on('click', 'button.rollback',function() {

    var rollback_id = $(this).find('[name="rollback_id"]').val();
    var form_id = $(this).attr('id');

    console.log(rollback_id);
    console.log(form_id);

    $('.secondary-actions #'+form_id+'-message-handling').fadeOut();
    $.ajax({
        type:       'POST',
        url:        'assets/class/login/actions/rollback.php',
        dataType:   'json',
        data: {
            rollback:   rollback_id
        },
        success:function(data) {
            if(data.error === true) {
                $('.secondary-actions #'+form_id+'-message-handling').text(data.message).fadeIn();
                console.log(data.message);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.secondary-actions #'+form_id+'-message-handling').fadeOut();
                }, 3500);
            }
                else {
                    $('.secondary-actions #'+form_id+'-message-handling').text(data.message).fadeIn();
                    console.log(data.message);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.secondary-actions #'+form_id+'-message-handling').fadeOut();
                    }, 3500);
                }
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            $('.secondary-actions #'+form_id+'-message-handling').text('Error | Check PHP log for information').fadeIn();
            console.log('Error | Check PHP log for information');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.secondary-actions #'+form_id+'-message-handling').fadeOut();
            }, 3500);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This one works perfectly, I mean the `'click'` event, it doesn't send me to another page which would be the action of the form, it's handled by the jQuery handler attached to the click event.

But the problem above is :

```
var rollback_id = $(this).find('[name="rollback_id"]').val();
var form_id = $(this).attr('id');

console.log(rollback_id);
console.log(form_id);
```

These two above output in the console `undefined`, why is that ? It should be something like `rollback_id = 'backup/logindb_backup_2012_02_02.sql'` and `form_id = 'backup-02-02-2012'`.

And the second part of my problem which I mentioned right in the head it's the `click` event, it doesn't work as the one for the above form does, when I click on the buttons, either of them, it just sends me to another page, the action of the form page which is `#`.

So here is the other form:

```
$form = array(
        '<form name="backup-form" class="backup-form" method="post" action="#">',
            '<fieldset class="backup-fields">',
                '<fieldset class="display-wrapper">',
                    '<label for="display" class="display-label">Backups</label>',
                    '<input type="text" name="display" class="display" value="' . $this->backups(false,true) . '" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" />',
                '</fieldset>',
                '<fieldset class="action-wrapper">',
                    '<button type="submit" name="clean" class="clean">Clean All</button>',
                    '<button type="submit" name="create" class="create">Create</button>',
                '</fieldset>',
            '</fieldset>',
        '</form>',
        '<div class="message-handling" class="message-handling"></div>'
    );
$form = implode("", $form);
echo $form;
```

In the form above `$this->backups(false,true)` it's just a number, it's not relevant to my question.

And here is the jQuery event triggers I'm trying to bind:

```
$('form.backup-form').on('click', 'button.clean',function() {
    console.log('Clean Button Pressed');
});


$('form.backup-form').on('click', 'button.create',function() {
    console.log('Create Button Pressed');
});
```

But these two don't work at all. And I have tried with `.delegate`, `.click`, `.submit` but those don't work either. So what could be the problem with these two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is this:

```
var rollback_id = $(this).find('[name="rollback_id"]').val();
var form_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Now, what is `$(this)` in this context? It's button.rollback. Not the form.

Do this instead:

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');
var rollback_id = form.find('[name="rollback_id"]').val();
var form_id = form.attr('id');
```

Comment: Oh, you're right, I haven't thought that `$(this)` is in fact the button and not the form. Let me try :)

Comment: This one does work, thanks for it. How about the second part of the question, what seems to be the problem with that ?

Comment: That i do not know - i tested it myself and found no error with it, here's a fiddle if you're curious: http://jsfiddle.net/2hPCb/ . The only thing i can think of is the placement of the script, is it in document.ready / the footer?

Comment: It's the footer, inside `<script>` tags. I'm using jQuery Tools, the Tabs. to load content in with the Ajax option for effect they have, and the only way is to put scripts like that inside the page I'm loading. Take a look at http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax.html and this one http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax-noeffect.htm .

Comment: You actually don't have to put scripts inside the page, you can use delegate methods like you already are, but just move them up. Example: `$("#IdOfTabsContainer").on("click", "form.backup-form input[type=button]", function() { alert("pressure was applied to a button!"); })`. This makes for cleaner code, when you can have everything in one place, and there's no need to load javascript except on pageload. Just make sure the delegate is present on DOM ready.

Comment: `$("#IdOfTabsContainer")` it's not clicked. If you look at the links, the tabs that are clicked are some href tags, and you have another set of divs contained in another div that contain the content, something like this: `<a href=''>One</a>` `<a href=''>Two</a>` and the divs with the content: `<div class="container"><div class=content></div><div class=content></div></div>`, so each of those `content` divs correspond to the href tags. And I apply the tabs like this : `$("ul.navigation").tabs("div.box-two > div", { effect 'ajax'; });` or something similar.

Comment: Yeah, but what i was trying to say is that you can easily bind delegate methods to the closest constant parent element, instead of dynamically loading new javascript. Here's an example, to let you see what i mean: http://jsbin.com/uvireq/5

Comment: I understand, just that I cannot generate the forms with js in this case, I need to do it with php because there some variables that are sent to the forms which are part of a big class, it's complicated. But I get your idea.

Comment: So I have tried something else. Instead of having the buttons of the form as `type="submit"`, I had it as `type="button"`. Now it seems to be working, but I get both messages in the console, as if I have pressed both buttons in the same time, why ?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.clean',function() {
    console.log('Clean Button Pressed');
});


$(document).on('click', 'button.create',function() {
    console.log('Create Button Pressed');
});
```

Comment: 3nigma is right. Opposite to .live(), .on() must be bound to an already existing element. And form.backup-form doesn't exist yet. So you'll have to go higher in the DOM tree and find a persistent element (possibly "document")

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but i think by "dynamically echoing out", he means it's PHP-generated, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes, it's PHP generated, but it should work for the last form too, because for the first form works as well and it's the same thing.